# How to keep changing a value through different activities?

Tags: android

All my activities will be:

```
public class XXXXXX extends HomePage {}
```

In my HomePage activity will be:

```
public class HomePage extends AppCompatActivity {int value;}
```

Although I have something such as click the button that value will add 1:

```
public class XXXXXX extends HomePage {
    int times;
    button Next;

    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (times) {
            case 0:
                value += 1;
                times++;
                break;

            case 1:
                startActivity(new Intent(XXXXXX.this, Showvalue.class));
                break;
```

After some activity, when I try to get the value after some activity, it will be show "0":

```
public class Showvalue extends Homepage {
    TextView textview;
    textview = (TextView) findViewByid(R.id.textview);
    textview.setText(String.valueOf(value));
}
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: You will need to manage passing this information in bundles. Instead of just `startActivity(new Intent(XXXXXX.this, Showvalue.class));`, create the intent, build the bundle apply the bundle to the intent, and then start the activity.

Comment: Code snipped formatting, grammar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because each activity is placed on stack with its own copy of `value`.

What you need to do is keep a static value in Application class so that only one copy of variable is available to all globally.

Create an Application class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static int value;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        value = 0;
    }

    public static int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public static void setValue(int newValue) {
        value = newValue;
    }
}
```

In `AndroidManifest.xml` specify the MyApplication class:

```
  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Now in one `activity`, use this to set values:

```
MyApplication.setValue(1);
```

...and in another to get `value`, use this:

```
int value = MyApplication.getValue();
```

...or reset it again. Whatever you need.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

So you just want to have the same int value present in each activity? if so, why don`t u make it static in your base activity or move to a separate utils class?